# What exactly is the physical setup of the Rayleigh-Jean's law derivation?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I've looked at multiple derivations online and they all seem to start by considering a perfectly reflective metallic box. I am under the impression that if you first add some material, such as a piece of carbon into the box, and second, bore a tiny hole into the closed box, then the entrance hole acts as a black body. That is, any light is completely "absorbed" and fully "emitted" by the hole.

I think this is because light entering is either immediately absorbed by the carbon or reflected by the carbon or walls until it gets eventually absorbed.

But in these derivations, all we seem to deal with is a metallic box with no particular substance inside to absorb radiation. Furthermore there is no "hole" to measure outgoing emitted radiation. I assume the latter problem is taken care of by measuring the radiation intensity inside the closed box instead.

Now for the former, if we assume there is, say, a piece of carbon which absorbs light, does this not violate the "standing wave" assumption? I think we can not have a mode consisting of a standing wave that isn't "disturbed" by the piece of carbon inside the box.

If we do not have a piece of carbon inside, what is then meant when these derivations mention "thermal equilibrium"? Thermal equilibrium with what?

I ask if there is a specific setup to this derivation that resolves these issues(if they are issues).

Here are [two](http://www.reading.ac.uk/physicsnet/units/3/3pha4/Lectures/l1.pdf) [sources](https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/derivation-of-the-rayleigh-jeans-law-part1/) that mention similar things that are causing an issue for me.

Comment: Metallic reflecting box? Hmm this is weird because reflective objects don't emit black body radiation. Are you sure you understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, because this seems to be the way to get the eletric field to vanish at the wall, setting up boundary condition. I'll try to add links to all the derivations I've seen.